# How many editions of Dungeons & Dragons are there?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

How many editions of Dungeons & Dragons are there?

Comment: As many as there are groups playing it. Every group has house rules and things the players and DM skip over.

Comment: [Related] [What are the big differences between the D&D editions?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/13212) • [How can I learn about other editions of D&D?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36358)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

As a generic answer for the non-hardcore fan, I think most people would define the following:

- OD&D (aka D&D 0e) including the original Brown Box and White Box versions from 1974.
- Classic (BECMI) D&D (including everything from BD&D in 1977 through the Rules Cyclopedia of 1991 and the Classic D&D Game starter set)
- AD&D 1st Edition (core books released 1977-1979)
- AD&D 2nd Edition (released 1989)
- D&D 3rd Edition (2000)
- D&D 3.5 Edition (revision of 3rd edition, released 2003)
- D&D 4th Edition (2008, including D&D Essentials, as D&D 4th edition has been erratad to the point that Essentials is at now)
- D&D 5th Edition (2014, aka D&D Next)

Certainly you could split it further (the various Mentzer/Moldvay differences, etc.) , but those are the major divides most gamers would likely note.

Of course, no edition of D&D survives contact with a gaming group intact; if there are 40,000 D&D sessions this weekend, there will be just about as many “versions” being played.

Comment: Question: is there a reason that O D&D supplements Greyhawk, Blackmoor, and Eldritch Wizardry are not included?  They introduced a lot of classes that became standards in later editions: thieves, Paladins, Monks, Druids.

Comment: @korvinstarmast I understand an "edition" to incorporate some set of rules which are intended to work together and are published by [legal entity who holds copyright over Dungeons & Dragons at that time]. So a book with new races, classes, and mechanics does not constitute a new edition when intended for use with existing material. A book which overhauls rules from 3rd party would not be a new edition. A book from WOTC (the current copyright holder) which does not reference other books would be a new edition.

Comment: @PipperChip You misunderstand my seven year old comment.  Those books are a part of the O D&D edition (see the Answer by RS Conley) along with the original Brown Box and White Box. Not including them is an error.  WoTC is utterly irrelevant to my comment, that was TSR published  material.  See also the answer by aramis, which is more correct.

Answer (score 66):

- Chainmail Fantasy Supplement in 1971
- Original Dungeons & Dragons published in 1974
  *Note that the basic game uses d6's for almost everything, and is written to use Chainmail as the combat system, rather than the "alternate combat system," which would later become the standard D&D combat mechanic. Further, only three classes exist - Fighting Man, Cleric, Magic-User — and neither multi-classing nor demihumans work the same as later.*
- Supplement I: Greyhawk published in 1975
  *The added rules made Dungeons & Dragon into a form we recognize today. It changes to the HD mechanic that is used in every later edition, added thieves and the thief skills, changed multiclassing towards what would be used in AD&D*
- Basic Dungeons & Dragons by Holmes in 1977
- Advanced Dungeons & Dragons in 1977-1979
- Basic/Expert Dungeons & Dragons by Moldvay/Cook in 1981
- Basic/Expert/Companion/Master/Immortal Dungeons & Dragons by Mentzer in 1983
- Unearthed Arcana for AD&D (*Some say that this made AD&D 1.5.*)
- Advanced Dungeons & Dragons 2nd Edition in 1989
- Rules Cyclopedia for Dungeons & Dragons in 1991
  *A one-book compilation of Mentzer BECM D&D, some consider this the definitive version of the original Dungeons & Dragons line.*
- Skills & Powers for AD&D 2nd edition in 1995
  *Some say that this made AD&D 2.5. It certainly is obvious, in that it changes to 12 attributes.*
- Dungeons & Dragons 3.0 in 2000
- Dungeons & Dragons 3.5 in 2003
- Dungeons & Dragons 4.0 in 2008
- Pathfinder in 2009
  *Put out by [Paizo](http://www.paizo.com), this version is based on [the d20 SRD](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=d20/article/srd35). It supplanted D&D 4.0 [as the market leader](http://www.icv2.com/articles/news/24224.html) in 2012. Some say it made D&D 3.75.*

  - D&D Next - Intermediate development version
- Dungeons & Dragons 5.0 in 2014

  - One D&D in 2022 - Development version

Comment: While I agree Pathfinder is essential in the story of D&D, it is technically not D&D and not needed in the updated answer

Comment: I don't agree for the 1st version of Pathfinder. Which was a clear successor to D&D 3.5 both in creative and market terms. D&D is both a brand and a family of systems. The reason the situation exists is because much of D&D 3.5 was released as open content by Wizards.

Answer (score 31):

Being a bit nitpicky... and using a "The rules are different enough that they characters have different capabilities and/or limits on advancement" meaning for edition, I'd say:

#### Not D&D but precursors to it:

- Chainmail
- Chainmail with Fantasy Supplement
- Braunstein

#### D&D

- Pre-6th Printing D&D (5x8's)
- 6th printing and later D&D (5x8's) - subtle changes due to renaming of Tolkien derived stuff
- either flavor of the 5x8's with the supplements I - VI - mechanically different from base box alone.
- Holmes Basic
- AD&D 1E
  Note that the 1978 printing is missing some elements in the 1981 printing; each printing seems to have included some errata changes. This was caught during a discussion of the lack of clerics for elves and dwarves - they're in the 1981, but not the 1978 printing of the PHB.
- Moldvay Basic & Cook Expert
- Revised AD&D 1E (new covers and minor errata)
- AD&D 1E + Unearthed Arcana (UA makes MAJOR rules alterations to what's in the core)
- Mentzer Basic, Expert, Companion, Master, Immortal.
- AD&D 2E
- Revised AD&D 2E
- Allston D&D Cyclopedia and Denning Basic (the big black box)
- Gazeteer D&D (Mentzer, or Denning & Allston with the GAZ line or HWR line alterations)
- AD&D 2E + Player's Option series
- D&D 3.0 (d20)
- D&D 3.5 (d20)
- D&D 4.0
- D&D 4 Essentials (4.1 from what I gather)
- D&D 5e aka D&D Next.
- One D&D

#### Post-D&D:

- Pathfinder (several of the 3.X dev team jumped ship to work on it)

#### Putting these into families:

- Early: either little book flavor without supplements, with chainmail. VERY different feel.
- BX/BECMI/BXCMI: Moldvay/Cook, Mentzer, Denning/Allston, Gazetteer.
- AD&D

  - 0E: little book with at least Supplements 1 & 2, or Holmes Basic
  - 1E: AD&D 1E and Revised 1E,
  - 1.5E: AD&D 1E+UA
  - 2E: AD&D 2E and Revised 2E
  - 2.5E, PO'd 2E: AD&D 2E with the player's option books.
- D20 line

  - D20 D&D: D&D 3.0, D&D 3.5
  - Continued under a new name: Pathfinder
- 4E: D&D 4E, D&D 4E Essentials.
- D&D Next

And that's without retroclones, pseudoclones, and knockoffs.

Note that, to me, a game edition can be any of the following:

1. The core rules were significantly revised and reworded.
2. The characters are distinctive enough that one can readily tell which edition was in use.
3. The mechanics are different enough that the character won't play the same.

Thus, the gaps between:

- Moldvay/Cook, Mentzer, and Alston/Denning, (Reason 1)
- AD&D 1 and 1.5 (Reason 2 and 3)
- AD&D 2 and 2.5 (Reason 2 & 3)
- original box, and original box plus supplements 1 & 2 (Reason 2 and 3)
- Pathfinder and 3.X (Reason 2. Just look at the class skills and skill levels.)

Comment: I got my errata from 1e's first printing DMG from Dragon magazine.  I still have the notes, but sadly, not the mag.

Answer (score 5):

[The Acaeum](http://www.acaeum.com/ddindexes/rulebooks.html) details the various editions and printings. It's well worth an extended browse just for the nostalgia of the cover scans. I'm going to say nine editions: OD&D, Holmes, Moldvay, Metzner, AD&D, 2e, 3e, 3.5e, and 4e.

Comment: make it 11: DND Next (5e playtest) and 5e

Comment: Make it 12: **One D&D** Playtest is out.