# What are the major differences between AD&D 1st Edition & AD&D 2nd Edition

Tags: adnd-1e, adnd-2e, edition-comparison

Supposedly on May 21st WoTC are going to release a premium limited edition reprinting of Dungeons & Dragons 2nd edition in of honor of the late Gary Gygax.
I already own the AD&D 1st edition books and am wondering if it's worth getting the second edition. I have heard 2nd edition be compared to 4E and other negatives about it. So what are the major (and minor) differences between AD&D 1st edition and AD&D 2nd edition and what are the upsides and negatives about 2nd edition?

---

Related: [What are the big differences between the D&D editions?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/13212/23970)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## Major Differences

1. the list of classes
2. the presumption of Non-Weapon Proficiencies
3. Advancement of Thief Skills
4. nature of Bards
5. Kits
6. Specialist Mages
7. Clerics
8. THAC0
9. Psionics

## The list of Classes

AD&D 1E Core: Assassin, Cleric, Druid, Fighter, Illusionist, Paladin, Ranger, Thief, Wizard. Bard is special, see below.

AD&D 1E+ UA: Assassin, Barbarian, Cavalier, Cleric, Druid, Fighter, Illusionist, Paladin, Ranger, Thief, Thief-Acrobat, Wizard. Bard is special, see below.

AD&D 2E: Bard, Cleric, Druid, Fighter, Magic User, Paladin, Ranger, Specialist Mage, Thief. Barbarian and Cavalier still exist, but as kits, which see below.

## Non-Weapon Proficiencies

While NWP's exist in late AD&D 1E, they are presumed to be optional add-ons, and not listed in adventures.

In AD&D 2E, while technically optional, almost all examples and almost all pregen characters include the Non-Weapon proficiencies. They are presumed as a part of the game line design. This is a huge change in the nature of adventures, too. The use of NWP's is expected in some adventures, and explicitly required for a few more.

## Thief Skills

In AD&D 1E, thief skills advance along specific tracks, and all characters of a given level have the same ones have the same base, modified for race, armor, and attributes. This also means NPC thieves do not need their scores listed, as they can be figured from the DM Screen on the fly.

In AD&D 2E, thief skills have a base at 1st level, but a pool of points added to that base at 1st level, and a smaller pool at each level thereafter. Thief skills must be listed for NPC's, as it's much harder to assign on the fly.

Further, in later 2E materials (Dark Sun, Skills & Powers), there are additional thief skills added, and PC thieves pick which ones they take at first level, and gain the remainder at 9th.

This also affects Bards, as in 2E, bards gain certain thief skills for being bards, and use the same points per level method as thieves.

## Bards

In AD&D 1E, the Bard in the PH can only be taken by dual-classed fighter/thief characters. The Character must be between 5th and 8th level as a fighter, then 4th and  7th as a thief, and then dual class into Bard. This requires some insane stats, and extensive play. Bards will likewise have extensive thief abilities, be competent fighters, and will not gain more HP for several levels due to the dual classing rules.

In AD&D 2E, Bards are a core class. The thief skills are a subset, not the full range. Fighting ability is weaker than fighters. HP are comparable to thieves.

Historical Note: The original Bard class in Strategic Review was closer to the 2E bard than the 1E presentation, but the details of ability were comparable to using the 1E bard as a core class.

## Kits (2E only)

The concept of Kits is mentioned in the 2E Core Rules, but they are not presented until the Player's Handbook Rules Expansions (PHBR series). A kit has a set of requirements, provides some bonus proficiencies, and occasionally, bonus special abilities. Many were somewhat extreme.

The equivalent role in 1E was filled by specialized subclasses presented in magazines, as exemplified by the Cavalier...

## Specialist Mages

AD&D 1E has 4 specialist mage classes, with only one, Illusionist, in the core rules. (The other 3 are in the Forgotten Realms Adventures rulebook.) Illusionist is presented as a full-up core class; the Forgotten Realms ones are full from the 3rd level on, and require core Magic User for levels 1-3. A few additional specialist classes appear in magazine articles.

AD&D 2E presents 8 specialist wizard subclasses as a single core class in the PHB. They differ from each other only in specific spells and attribute requirements.

There is no specific specialist spell lists, but every spell has specific school attributions, and those schools are the basis for the specialist classes. All specialists spells are available to core magic users.

An additional variant class is presented in Tome of Magic, the Wild Mage.

## Clerics, Priests, and Druids.

In both games, both cleric and druid are presented as a core class.

In AD&D 1E, they have separate, and only somewhat overlapping, spell lists.

In 2E, both use Priest Spells. 2E Clerical spells are assigned to specific Spheres, with a number being in more than one sphere. Clerics have several spheres; druids have a specified set of spheres. Provision is made in the PHB to allow for creation of similarly specialized priest classes; further details are in the PHBR for Clerics...

Since the whole of the priestly spell list is unavailable to core priests, this makes it more difficult to select what spells are available to a given priest... but it's also now a smaller list for any given priest.

## THAC0

THAC0, "To Hit Armor Class 0," was a shortcut used in some later AD&D 1E materials, which imperfectly reflected the AD&D 1E To Hit tables, with their flat spots.

THAC0 was adopted as the official mechanic for AD&D 2E, and the To-Hit tables reworked to make use of it.

This may seem trivial, but it makes negative AC's much harder to hit for low level characters, as AD&D 1E has a 6 AC entries for a To-Hit of 20. So a Modified roll of 21 in the tables hits an AC 5 lower than using THAC0. (As a reminder, the modifiers were situational and attribute only; THAC0 itself is modified in AD&D 2E, and table of roll needed is indexed by Level (on a class basis) and AC being attacked.

## Psionics

In 1E, psionics are in the core rules, in an appendix, relatively unchanged from their Original Edition version in Eldritch Wizardy (Supplement 3).

In 2E, psionics are in a PHBR rulebook, not the core rules. The mechanics get reworked entirely, and while having throwbacks to the older rules, they are quite different in execution. The use of proficiency-score checks, and the methods of generating Psionic Points are very different.

## Lesser changes

- The specific modifiers for attack rolls have changed.
- Many specific spells have significant explicit changes
- specific wordings changing resulting in different interpretations on many spells
- specifics of the Weapons vs Armor tables differ within AD&D 2E; they are different as well from AD&D 1E.
- Specific entries for the XP earned by non-combat methods.
- Many monsters have changes, sometimes extensive and substantial. Especially Dragons.
- Angels, Demons and Devils are not called that in AD&D 2E. Baatezu and Tan'ari are demons and devils.

## So what's the same???

Mode of play remains unchanged. The relationship of the Initial 3 classes (Fighter, Mage, Cleric) remain the same, and the Thief as well in relation to those. The Druid, Paladin, and Ranger as well retain their core character.

The general modes of advancement are the same, even tho the specific methods of earning XP have been expanded, and the XP tables are close (tho not always identical).

The basic mode for magic is still the same, and is still spells per day.

The save categories remain unchanged. The unique monsters - illithids, rust monsters, beholders, and several others are the same as ever in general terms, even if some specifics vary.

## Bottom Line

2E is a different game from 1E, but shares much of the heritage. They're able to borrow across, but rules as written, they are not the same games. There was far less difference between Original Edition D&D as expanded and AD&D 1e than between 1E and 2E.

Comment: Great answer. The last sentence raised an eyebrow: a bit of disbelief, but more curiosity. I could maybe see an argument for that. But great answer.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Almost every bit of AD&D 1E mechanics was previously present in either supps 1-3 or Strategic Review or Dragon articles.

Comment: Taken as a whole it feels quite different, but I see what you mean since, now that you remind me, I recall reading that much of 1e was the collection of Gygax's opinion of current best practices and publishing. I guess that could be seen as 0e having its own transitional .5 edition.

Comment: Indeed, it has several. Holmes being the penultimate Original Ed product, rather than the first AD&D 1E product, IMO. OrEd without supplements is a very different game, but once you get Sup 1 in play, it's very much on the road to AD&D1E. 2E was a rewrite from 2nd principles, rather than best practices. But I've just added "as expanded" for clarity. Keep in mind - I got OrEd only as a block - including Sups 1 & 2.

Comment: is it in 1e->2e that all of the demons and devils drop out of circulation, temporarily? I have acquaintances for whom that's a defining characteristic (whenever it was that it happened). Also, is this the time of the re-branding of *Deities & Demigods* to *Legends & Lore*? (In the same vein.)

Comment: @nitsua60 Followup questions should be asked as new questions, generally speaking.

Comment: @nitsua60 yes - 2E included the renames of demons and devils to Baatezu and Tan'ari

Comment: @GMJoe sorry--not really thinking of that as a follow up, but as a possible suggestion for inclusion as a difference between the editions. (I just wasn't sure that I had the right edition-change in mind.)

Comment: @nitsua60 no, the first printing of Legends & Lore was 1st ed, a rebranding of Deities and Demigods, which itself had printings with different content, confusingly.

Comment: Little-cited fact, that although THAC0 was made official in 2e, it was actually introduced in 1e in the Battlesystem Boxed Set.

Comment: @keithcurtis Before that, even, in adventures. Hence why I say, "Late 1E"

Comment: @aramis I missed the previous paragraph. I retract all of my nerdy outrage. :)

Comment: Magic Resistance works very differently in 1e vs 2e: in 1st, it scales with the level of the caster being resisted, with 11th level being the base, so a printed 5% MR is effectively 55% against a 1st level caster.

Comment: "specifics of the Weapons vs Armor tables differ within AD&D 2E" is this a reference to some bonuses / penalties specified in Combat & Tactics, or somewhere else?  I'd like to see the citation

Comment: @ucbpaladin The best I can get you in the 2E is that it's in the weapons vs armor rule in the DMG. (My electronic copies are the RTFs from the Core Rules CDs; my dead tree is in another state).

Comment: "Specific entries for the XP earned by non-combat methods" -- the XP system was changed in other ways too, generally with an increased emphasis on actions and away from XP for treasure. This had a knock-on effect in the gold economy of the game, as PCs were no longer likely to be dragging huge hauls home. This is particularly noticeabe in the costs for level training, going from 1500gp per level per week down to 100gp per level per week.

Comment: @Erics Not that anyone I've played AD&D (either) with actually used level training, let alone the costs per week. I ran exactly one campaign with training times. Players hated it.

Answer (score 14):

**Not Much**

Second Edition is mainly a cleaned up, consolidated version of First Edition. Most of the differences between AD&D First and Second Editions were minor.  In fact, the most notable ones were introduced into 1e already - using *THAC0* (To Hit Armor Class Zero, a single number) instead of using to-hit tables and *non-weapon proficiencies* (NWPs) as skills were introduced earlier in Dragon Magazine and supplements (the two Survival Guides most notably).  Many GMs at the time freely intermixed 1e and 2e, especially adventures.  I happily ran 1e adventures like Scourge of the Slavelords and others using 2e rules with no modification.

The renaming of devils and demons Tanar'ri and Baatezu was not much of a "real" change but a "PR" change that was planned to soothe non-gamers but agitated some gamers.

**But Some**

Probably the two largest changes that affected gameplay were kits and the DMG.

- There were a line of splatbooks that introduced "kits," variations on the normal classes.  As with anything like this, many were decried for being munchkiny or unbalanced; now in the age of 3e+ character optimization they look like such minor differences in retrospect.
- The 1e DMG was noted for its crazy Gygaxian toolkit of random tables and lore.  The 2e DMG was a mainly pointless book because it didn't have much of that - after a initial read you went there for the treasure tables and magic item descriptions and that was it.

There's a host of small changes so minor that I never cared much even at the time.  Demihuman level limits higher, some tampering with what races and classes were available, damage caps on blasting spells, no XP for GP (demoted to an optional rule), no level titles, two-weapon fighting. No breasts in the Monster Manual was probably the most traumatic.

Oh, and @starwed points out the clerical spheres and wizard schools - that's a good point; it limited what spells could be cast but gave some new powers; it was a significant power-up of the casters once enough splatbooks came out to allow enough choices to twink out.

Answer (score 6):

AD&D 2nd Edition compared to AD&D is more evolution than revolution. It's really an update in book form (the internet for consumers at that point was BBS's, think of it as an all text based DOS'ish website that only one person per phone line dedicated to the BBS could visit at a time). If you read the foreword in the 2nd edition PHB, they basically confirm my opening sentence. 2nd Edition is almost AD&D 'a la carte'. For every core rule, there's optional rules that may modify or outright contradict the core rule. Ex: player death at 0 hp, or player unconcious at 0 hp, dead at -10 hp. Ultimately, it's up to the DM to decide what to order. So really, it's the game that TSR would have designed in the first instance had they known what they later would come to learn from player feedback, letters to the D&D magazine editors, etc. AND... 'media pushback' / overeacting overprotective parents groups...

It's also the 'ready for prime-time' edition. You may have a hard time believing it, but at one point, parents groups, religious groups and in extreme cases, religious parents groups had the same moral panic over D&D that they've had over other things such as 'rock & roll, heavy metal, hip hop, pre-marital sex, etc'... Believing it all led to drugs, suicide and devil worship. Not that any study I'm aware of ever described a causal link between D&D and the afore-mentioned self-destructive behaviors... Not bad for a game that's purported to be enjoyed by youthful, male shut-ins world wide. So the game's content was scrubbed with a toothbrush to avoid setting off parental overeaction responses, leaving us with the most High Fantasy, Lord of the Rings'ish edition ever, while simulataneously holding on to a pulpy, gritty realism.