# Are there any systems similar to Pathfinder's Kingmaker that are more complex and realistic?

Tags: game-recommendation, realm-management

I'm looking for systems similar to Kingmaker (where the PCs rule and expand a kingdom), except I want it to be much more realistic and complex.

A few examples of what I mean:

- Instead of 'Building Points', actual resources are required (ex: wood, stone, ores, etc.)
- Instead of the king and his most important men exploring and traveling dangerously, they'd send other people.
- Trading to be much more emphasized and complex (tariffs, specific trading goods to import and export).
- Diplomacy to allow for embassies, so towns can work together (end up getting free trade agreements, maybe other benefits).

Comment: I know of several things which add on to Kingmaker's system (some published, some just posts on a forum), and some things which address running a keep, or designing a city, or such.  But nothing for *ruling* a city/area/kingdom that's more in-depth than Kingmaker.  I'm definitely looking forward to seeing what answers this gets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Adventurer Conqueror King](http://www.autarch.co/) address many of the same topics as Paizo's Kingmaker. Also the treasure generation system has been aligned with economic assumptions of the domain system. The rules address mercantile ventures, and building not only of castles but other types of holdings. The different elements are defined in natural terms of gold pieces, days of constructs, number of personnel rather than a abstract system of points.

The rulebook can be [purchased from here](http://www.rpgnow.com/browse.php?manufacturers_id=4277).

More narrow in focus are Columbia Games [Harnmanor](http://www.columbiagames.com/cgi-bin/query/harn/cfg/single.cfg?product_id=4751) and [Pilot's Almanac](http://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=1247) (if you can find it). While having detailed mechanics both are highly playable. If you are familiar with Classic Traveller they are of similar complexity. The individual supplements also function well as a standalone rules subsystem. Harn is a low fantasy medieval setting so it supplement are usable with any fantasy RPGs that has a fantasy medieval implied setting like Pathfinder or Dungeons & Dragons.

Comment: Just a heads up: ACKS appears to be built on an AD&D base, rather than being either a completely new system or a d20/3.x derivative or a Pathfinder addon.  (This is *not* a mark against it, just a comment on what it is and isn't compatible with.)

Comment: I'm not sure your link to the ACKS rules is supposed to be a public link. The PDF rules are for sale and that book is not on their download page.

Comment: Yup apparently when you log in your download page is a mix of what you paid for and what free my bad. Fixed my answer.

Comment: @Bobson To be accurate, ACKS is based on Moldvay/Cook/Marsh's B/X D&D.

Comment: Also, +1 for ACKS!

Comment: The "Domains at War" book for ACKS may also be relevant to this, if your players ever want to lead their realms to war.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - Good to know.  I'm not very conversant in old versions of D&D - I know enough to recognize that it *is* a pre-3.0 version, but that's about it.  Is there a question around that discusses the differences?

Comment: @Bobson We do in fact! Here you go :) http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/13212/what-are-the-big-differences-between-the-dd-editions

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - I figured there was one around.  Thanks!