# How many D&D rule books from 1st edition to 5th are there?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

Im doing an item on D&D for my class and i thought that the amount of D&D rule books would be an interesting statistic.I can imagine there are hundreds of them but i cant seem to be able to find the exact number anywere.
please help if you can.

Comment: Define rulebook? Core rules only, or supplements? Do boxed sets count as one or more? What about when the number of rulebooks for an eddition changed? I suspect this question isn't as simple as you might think.

Comment: Official books? Officially-licensed books? Magazines? Magazine collections? Official web articles? What all do you want?

Comment: Can you let us know where you have looked and what you've found (and why you aren't sure that "the number")? One reason given for downvotes is "does not show any research effort." I suspect some of those may come your way as your question is written now.

Comment: While not exactly a duplicate, [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/336/how-many-editions-of-dungeons-dragons-are-there) might be useful to you, and [this answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/499/14988) pretty much answers your question.

Comment: @Adeptus FWIW that link does not give a count of rule books, but it's a great summary of the editions.