# How to use Gestalt in 5th edition?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, gestalt

The Gestalt is a pretty nice feature from 3.5 edition, allowing to pick 2 classes for every character level.

I couldn't find any information about it in Player's Handbook and neither in Game Master's Guide.

**How could it be resolved as homebrewed?** What would happen if you would gain the same feature twice? Could you pick the same class twice in order to get two archetypes? **Answers must include Your own experience with decribed homebrewed rules.

Comment: This question concerns me, because it's simultaneously asking us (a) do the gestalt rules exist, (b) if they don't please share some custom Gestalt rules. That's two very different questions at once, and (b) is a significant design exercise in its own right that might not be appropriate for the Stack to handle. Could we trim this down to just *"I'm interested in doing Gestalt in D&D 5e, are there rules for it already?"*? That makes answers like the one we've already got of "no but nobody's stopping you from using the D&D 3.5e rules anyway" suit just fine.

Answer (score 15):

Gestalt is a system feature of only one edition of D&D compared to seven or eight editions<sup>([or more, depending on how you count](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/336/how-many-editions-of-dungeons-dragons-are-there))</sup> that don't feature it. It was invented for and arose out of the particular design philosophies of D&D 3.5e, which aren't design philosophies shared by the other editions. It was not a feature of 4e, and there's no reason to expect that it will ever be a feature of 5e.

That said, there's nothing stopping someone from applying the [3.5e gestalt campaign variant rules](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/gestaltCharacters.htm) verbatim in a 5e campaign, because the way they're written they *could* be applied to any edition of D&D, regardless of how alien the gestalt class concept is to a given edition's design philosophy.

(But remember it's a *campaign* variant. Nobody can just choose to play a gestalt character on their own.)

Comment: Also one thing to add there as he had asked about experiences: gestalt characters are always WAY more powerful than normal ones and some combinations can be broken....way broken. same feature twice: once is ignored then ;)