# Is there a way to change 3e stats into 5e stats?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-3e, conversion

Is there any way (preferably and online generator or something akin to that, but I can do it by hand too), to quickly and hopefully simply, change a stat block like

> Medium Aberration
> HP 8d8+8 (44 hp)
> Initiative +6 (+2 Dex, +4 Improved Initiative)
> Speed 30 ft.
> Armor Class 15 (+2 Dex, +3 natural)
> Base Attack/Grapple: +6/+7
> Attack: Tentacle +8 melee (1d4+1)
> Full Attack: 4 tentacles +8 melee (1d4+1)
> Space/Reach: 5 ft./5 ft.
> Special Attacks: Mind blast, psionics, improved grab, extract
> Special Qualities: Spell resistance 25, telepathy 100 ft.
> Saves: Fort +3, Ref +4, Will +9
> Abilities: Str 12, Dex 14, Con 12, Int 19, Wis 17, Cha 17
> Skills: Bluff +11, Concentration +11, Diplomacy +7, Disguise +3 (+5 acting), Hide +10, Intimidate +9, Knowledge (any) 12, Listen +11, Move Silently +10, Sense Motive +7, Spot +11
> Feats: Combat Casting, Improved Initiative, Weapon Finesse
> Climate/Terrain: Underground
> Orgnization: Solitary, pair, inquisition (3-5), or cult (3-5 plus 6-10 grimlocks)
> Challenge Rating: 8
> Treasure: Double standard
> Alignment: Usually lawful evil
> Advancement: By character class
> Level Adjustment: +7
> [Source](https://dumpstatadventures.com/blog/deep-dive-the-mind-flayer)

Into a stat block like this

> Medium aberration, lawful evil
> Armor Class 15 (breastplate)
> Hit Points 71 (13d8 + 13)
> Speed 30 ft.
> Str 11 (+0) | Dex 12 (+1) | Con 12 (+1), | Int 19 (+4) | Wis 17 (+3) | Cha 17 (+3)
> Saving Throws lnt +7, Wis +6, Cha +6
> Skills Arcana +7, Deception +6, Insight +6, Perception +12, Persuasion +6, Stealth +4
> Senses darkvision 120ft., passive Perception 16
> Languages Deep Speech, Undercommon, telepathy 120 ft.
> Challenge 7 (2,900 XP)
> Magic Resistance. The mind flayer has advantage on saving throws against spells and other magical effects.
> Innate Spellcasting (Psionics). The mind flayer’s innnate spellcasting ability is intelligence (spell save DC 15). ITT can innately cast the following spells, requiring no concentration: At will - deter thoughts, levitate. 1/day each: dominate monster, plane shift (self only)
> Tentacles. Melee Weapon Attack: +7 to hit, reach 5ft., one target. Hit 15 (2d10+4) psychic damage. If the target is medium or smaller, it is grappled (East ape DC 15) and must succeed on a DC 15 Intelligence saving throw or be stunned until this grapple ends.
> Extract Brain. Melee Weapon Attack: +7 to hit, reach 5 ft., one incapacitated humanoid grappled by the min flayer. Hit: 55 (10d10) piercing damage. If this damage reduces the target to 0 hit points, the mind flayer kills the target by extracting and devouring its brain.
> Mind Blast (Recharge 5-6). The mind flayer magically emits psychic energy in a 60-foot cone. Each creature in that area must succeed on a DC 15 Intelligence saving throw or take 22 (4d8+4) psychic damage add be stunned for one minute. A creature can repeat the saving throw at the end of each of its turns, ending the effect on itself on a success.
> [Source](https://dumpstatadventures.com/blog/deep-dive-the-mind-flayer)

If not, are there any non-quick and easy ways?

Comment: At least related (dupe?): [Where can I find advice on adapting characters from past editions to 5E?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/171122)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/171122/where-can-i-find-advice-on-adapting-characters-from-past-editions-to-5e) has a useful link from Wizards of the Coast. [This document](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/DnD_Conversions.pdf) contains guidelines on converting to 5e, including a "Quick Conversions" section on the last page, with a subsection for Monsters. For third edition monsters, that section includes:

> Most statistics in third edition include the creature’s ability scores. Use the following parameters:
>
> - Armor Class can be an average of touch AC and actual AC, or 20 percent lower than in third edition. The upper limit is 22.
> - Attack roll modifiers are the appropriate ability score modifier + 3.
> - Saving throw DCs are 10 + the appropriate ability score modifier.
> - If a creature has to make a check or saving throw, use its ability score modifiers. Grant it a +3 bonus if it should be good at the roll.

Good luck.

It's worth noting that while ability scores in 3e tend to be higher than the 5e equivalents, the quick conversions only grant a +3 proficiency bonus. This will generally keep attacks for high CR creatures near sane levels, though do not be afraid to hard-cap attacks at +12 (the DMG recommended attack bonus for a Challenge 20 monster), at least for non-epic foes.

Comment: Have you used this method? Ability score scaling was wildly different between these editions, and so I would not expect great results from these rules.

Comment: @KRyan I have found that locking Proficiency at +3 balances out the (generally larger) Ability Scores in 3E. Ability score *numbers* are very consistent since 3E (i.e. a 20 gives a +5 bonus), though the progression and expected value has varied pretty wildly.

Comment: Yeah, 3e PCs don’t have any hard cap, and the “soft cap” is much, much higher than 20. Monsters followed suit, more or less. So particularly at higher levels/CR, I would be concerned. But excellent point about the +3 proficiency cap. Pointing out the ability score difference and how the cap can counteract it (and does in your experience) would be valuable commentary to add to this answer, I think.