# In the first "Eye of the Beholder" game, does lower AC mean the target is harder to hit?

Tags: character-creation, adnd-2e, armor-class

I am not sure whether character adjustment in the first [*Eye of the Beholder*](https://www.gog.com/game/forgotten_realms_the_archives_collection_one) game works accurately. I see that AC depends only on DEX:

| DEX | AC (Human Male) |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 14 |
| 4 | 13 |
| 5 | 12 |
| 6 | 11 |
| 7–14 | 10 |
| 15 | 9 |
| 16 | 8 |
| 17 | 7 |
| 18 | 6 |

Screenshot (playing with values): [[Eye of the Beholder 1 - Character modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPDTX.png)]

The *Eye of the Beholder* game manual says:

> **Armor Class** (**AC**) measures how difficult a larget is to hit and damage — the lower the AC value, the harder the target is to hit. Good AC can indicate different things. [...]

My characters currently have AC about -6, and they are doing just fine, resistant to most hits.

But random resources (e.g. [Roll20](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Armor#content)) I've found appear to indicate the higher AC, the better.

What am I missing?

Comment: Nowhere in your post do you mention that you're asking about AD&D 2e rules. The first link you provide *and* the screenshot are from a video game which, as the close banner states, *is* off-topic here and the "random resource" you link is from D&D 5e so yeah, it's unclear exactly what you're asking about and what you seem to be asking about (the video game) is off-topic. It's amazing that someone was able to provide an answer anyway.

Comment: It's pretty clear that the question is about the concept of Armor Class rather than the content of the video game.  Although the OP could have done more research into the differences between game editions, and which edition their game was from, the question itself is on-topic.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey While the querent did not mention [adnd-2e], there are many folks who recognize that particular RPG. Plus, while not all video games are inherently *on* topic, the TSR/SSL RPGs from the 80's and 90's, even the early 2000's mostly use the same game rules as the tabletop games, and are strongly tied to tabletop RPGs. So too, had miroxlav been able to recognize that that this was 2e, he'd have had a good chance of not having to ask in the first place.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey Being called amazing is a nice way for me to start my day.  (And I think that's why "ask the experts" is the SE schtick.  )

Comment: @Chemus: The quote from the game manual (or rather, an image of that quote) has been there since the question was originally asked. Nobody else edited it in.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey – By editing I made the screenshot less dominant. Since I am entering the world of D&D via manuals to these games and they explain how the rules (and engine which simulates them) actually work, I am learning from there. I saw "Advanced Dungeons & Dragons v2" on the title screen but I had no idea how relevant this could be. Also, honestly, I did not expect that there could be such a difference between rules versions, that some important value like AC can be completely reverted from version to version. So the answer actually surprised me a bit.

Comment: @JFL – I like that they attempt to respect D&D rules. From the link in the question you can reach to the entire triology and using [The All-Seeing Eye](https://ase.zorbus.net) you can "teach" your party to draw dungeon map as they go (keep all other map insights switched off). The only disadvantage of the ASE is that it allows to hold two primary weapons at once (for original realism, you have to avoid doing that). I like that the EOB and its faithful clone [Lands of Lore 1](https://www.gog.com/game/lands_of_lore_1_2) (not 2 and 3) do a DM with AD&D rules for me.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

#### Lower AC is better for that game's D&D version

That [video game](https://www.gog.com/game/forgotten_realms_the_archives_collection_one) (in your screenshot) and table derived from it are based on *Advanced Dungeons & Dragons*, **2nd edition** – which uses the THAC0 ("To Hit Armor Class 0") system, in which lower armor class values are better (and negative AC values are both possible and even better than low positive values).

In the current (5th) edition of D&D, and in each of the WotC-published editions, a higher value is better since they are based on the [d20 System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D20_System).  Your link to Roll20.net is to the 5th-edition D&D rules, and that uses a "higher is better" system.  That change, from TSR to WoTC, happened starting with the 3rd edition of *Dungeons & Dragons*, published in 2000.  (WoTC bought out TSR in 1997.)

[Not all D&D versions are the same.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/336/22566) You have to read the label.

Having a high Dexterity, in 2nd-edition AD&D, makes increasingly useful Armor Class adjustments (-2, -3, -4) as the Dexterity score gets higher.

Comment: Is there a specific AD&D edition when this mechanism changed? (So it can be told based on given rules edition number?)

Comment: Yes, it changed when WOTC took over, with 3rd edition.  All AD&D games had "lower is better" as their AC system. (So did the Original and Basic games...)

Comment: @miroxlav To be pedantic, AD&D *is* a specific edition of Dungeons and Dragons, though that's understandably opaque to folks who are new to the hobby (particularly because that edition was published from 1989 to 2000).

Comment: @JoelHarmon To be even more pedantic, AD&D was two editions, one from 1977 to 1989 and one from 1989-2000. (I date it to when the Monster manual coming out, you can argue that it didn't go official until the DMG came out).

Comment: You could mention how the calculation using THAC0 (To Hit Armor Class 0) differs from the d20 system, which would illustrate why a lower armor class is better in that system.

Comment: @Seth I might consider that, but as they are not playing the later game, or the PC game based on a later game, I am not sure if that's within scope.

Comment: "In the current (5th) edition of D&D, and in each of the WoTC editions, a higher value is better since they are based on the d20 system."
Uh, THAC0 was also d20 based. So no, that's not the reason a higher value is better

Comment: @Kevin, the THAC0 system used d20, but the editions published under Wizards of the Coast is literally called the "d20 System" and is trademarked as such.

Comment: @SethR: The capitalization of "System" does help distinguish it from a generic descriptor for d20-based RPG systems, so I've edited the answer to clarify that (and add a link to the Wikipedia page for the d20 System).