# Detecting Telepathy through Detect Magic

Tags: dnd-5e, divination, telepathy

Situation looks like that:

My character casts Detect Magic, at the same time other creature uses his ability (this is not a spell) and comunicate with others through Telepathy.

In that case, should my character at least notice that something is happening?

Comment: Which Edition of D&D? there's like [8 to 20 branches of them](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/336/how-many-editions-of-dungeons-dragons-are-there), many of them differently in setup for the spell. Without knowing the edition, we can't answer.

Comment: This is for 5e.

Comment: in other words: depends on how the creature's ability is worded.

Comment: Welcome to the stack, have a look at the [tour] when you have a moment. I’ve closed this as a duplicate, as I do believe the linked question is asking the same thing, and the answers do a good job explaining the scenario you seem to be asking about here.